# Cocoa Pods - Multiple Dependencies

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm new to working with cocoa pods and having a trouble of getting work another dependency which is given in the same Podfile. 
The issue I persume is that, it's seeking for headers of the second dependency within the first dependency.

Podfile:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your project references an old framework that you had in your Downloads folder, but it is now missing. Remove the reference and try to build again.

Comment: Thanks Schemetrical. This solved the problem half of the way, the issue was with dependency that i was going to install. I've done it without pods finally.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand how to read those errors.

For example, this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FLAnimatedImage", refereced from:
    objc-class-ref in SampleViewController.o
```

meaning that an objective-c object which called "FLAnimatedImage", in "SampleViewController.m" file has a broken reference for x86_64 architecrues (different devices working with different proccessor architectures).

You should enter this class (SampleViewController), and try to understand where this object (FLAnimatedImage) is declared (one of the "import ..."). In your case, i think it's just because your old library or project doesn't support in the x86_64 architecture.

so, for your project file and all library files (all file with ".xcodeproj" suffix):

1. click on the .xcodeProj
2. choose your currect target (usually you should update your architectures to all targets, then choose your project instead).
3. choose tab "build settings"
4. find "valid architectures" (you can search it in search bar)
5. add "x86_64" to existing architectures.
6. make sure that "build debug architectures"=no.

Good Luck !